# ExcelScript Type Definnitions

Tags: office-scripts

Really sorry if this has been answered somewhere… Does anyone know if a `@types/` `npm` library exists for ExcelScript? Or even an `ExcelScript.d.ts` file somewhere?

Comment: It's not open source so I don't think so.  This is as close as you'll come I'd say ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript?view=office-scripts ... happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The type definitions for Office Scripts are not open source. A copy of those definitions is used to generate the [reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript?view=office-scripts). It is updated shortly after the internal definitions are updated. You can find a public copy of the .d.ts file here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-scripts-docs-reference/blob/main/generate-docs/script-inputs/excel.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

Sumurthy on GitHub wrote a file, index.d.ts, to do this. You can take a look at that file [here](https://github.com/sumurthy/officescripts-projects/tree/main/misc).